# Google Sheets. Location of viewers in sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to get a listing of current viewers in a given Google Sheets, and very important, the location in the spreadsheet. It concerns a spreadsheet with multiple sheets, so it needs to include the sheet name as well.
At the moment I cannot advance beyond:

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Location = SS.getViewers();
```

This gives me the listing of viewers, but not the sheet they are in.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning**: as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getviewers), the function `.getViewers()` returns the users who have permission to view or comment the document, not the users who are currently viewing it. At the moment though, there is **no** function that returns the user list you want.

If you think it's really important, you can [file a feature request](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features).

Comment: Thanks. It is a severe shortcoming of google sheets :-(

Comment: Please accept the answer, it will help everyone who has the same problem to quickly find this. Thanks!